# AdalServiceException: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

My Web App, which was working fine till yesterday, has suddenly started throwing the exception below since yesterday.

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)

AdalServiceException: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided. Trace ID: de067aef-cfed-4468-9488-633704897701 Correlation ID: e0449ed4-02ab-4cf2-8859-e5f049e5f8e7 Timestamp: 2019-12-11 00:02:30Z Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.GetResponseAsync(bool respondToDeviceAuthChallenge)

[image]

From brief investigation, I found that some service/application has expired. But, not able to figure out which one. Because, in "App Registrations" in Active Directory, all registrations which were expired have now been updated with new client secrets.

Also, this has started happening after Base64 encoding was done for setting Blob Metadata with;

```
Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(metaattribute.Trim()))
```

The indexer has been given FieldMapping decoder as below;

```
FieldMapping("MetaAttribute", "MetaAttribute", FieldMappingFunction.UrlDecode())
```

How do I troubleshoot this? I don't see "App Service" registration in "App Registration". Is that the cause?

Comment: Please provide your code here.

Comment: Which code specifically? Any random action in the web application fails with the error above. The code for Encoding is as shared above.

Comment: According to the error, obviously you use the [adal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) in your code, could you provide the code where you use the Azure AD App?

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new Client Secret Key (in Active Directory->App Registrations) for my Media Services application and replace the old key with new one in the code. Not sure why Azure doesn't give any specific warnings before token expiration date..

Comment: I've done this 15 times but still I get the error, intermittently

Comment: Can you please point out, where does it needs to be replaced in the code?

Comment: @johnstaveley, I'm doing the same, number of time, still getting error, and what code needs to be altered?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are copying the value of your App Secret and not the ID. I made this mistake once. :)